# get UIImageView under another UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, tags

I have some question.

I have added UIImageView on self.view. Than a added another UIImageView. And second UIImageView can move on self.view.

Can I get tag of first UIImageView when second UIImageView over first UIImageView?

Thanks

Comment: not clear but try to set tag to uiimageview first then try to get the tag.Set tag:- firstimageview.tag=1; get tag:- int tag=firstimageviiew.tag;

Comment: yes, i set tag. Only must to know how to determine what UIImageView under another UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
First give tag to firstimageview and secondimageview then using that tag you can identify any image view using below code
 UIImageView *firstimgeview = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:firstimageviewtag];
 UIImageView *secondimgeview = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:secondimageviewtag];
```

Comment: yes, but than i must compare coordinats of firtimgeview and secondimgeview? And if they equils, than firstimgeview under secondimgeview, yes?

Comment: yes you are right and also you can get by comparing center of both image view if both image view center are equal then both are overlaps